# Max value along with timestamp retrieval in opentsdb

Tags: api, opentsdb

Say, I have below time series for metric `cpu.load_1min`

```
t0    t1    t2    t3    t4    t5    t6    t7    t8    t9
 0    10    90    20    80    30    70    40    60    50
```

I wanna extract the highest value along with its timestamp. in above case it's `<t2, 90>`. I also want the timestamp to be the exact timestamp without downsampling.

And I'm talking about generating a 3-month timespan report for over 10 thousand servers. So querying them all back and then do the max operation myself is really not my option.

I found that `/api/query` or `/api/query/exp` could not do it

Please help me out, thx.

Comment: kindly, share the api call

Comment: As if you're using the default sum aggregator, just use the max aggregator - http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/query/aggregators.html#max